# Why no generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, ordereddictionary

Why is there no generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?

Prior to posting this message, i did see:
[No generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary)

But that just confirms that it does not exist.  Not *why* it does not exist.

There are a few custom implementations I've seen, including:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx

But why did Microsoft not include it in the base .net library?  Surely they had a reason for not building a generic.... but what is it?

Thanks

EDIT: Perhpase this should be moved to programmers.se.com... but I don't know how to move it.

Comment: Good question, I've occasionally been frustrated by this lack as well.

Comment: What was the duplicate post for this? I see no links to a duplicate post that answers "why"...

Comment: Maybe they mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary