# Which .NET collection is faster: enumerating foreach Dictionary<>.Values or List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, enumeration

Are one of these enumerations faster than the other or about the same? (example in C#)

Case 1:

```
Dictionary<string, object> valuesDict;

// valuesDict loaded with thousands of objects

foreach (object value in valuesDict.Values) { /* process */ }
```

Case 2:

```
List<object> valuesList;

// valuesList loaded with thousands of objects

foreach (object value in valuesList) { /* process */ }
```

UPDATE:

Background:

The dictionary would be beneficial for keyed search elsewhere (as opposed to iterating through a list), but the benefit would be diminished if iterating through the dictionary is much slower than going through the list.

UPDATE:
Taking the advice of many, I've done my own testing.

First, these are the results. Following is the program.

Iterate whole collection
Dict: 78
Keyd: 131
List: 76

Keyed search collection
Dict: 178
Keyd: 194
List: 142800

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace IterateCollections
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Text;
    }

    public class KeyedData : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, Data>
    {
        protected override string GetKeyForItem(Data item)
        {
            return item.Id;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Data>();
            var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Data>();
            var keyd = new KeyedData();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                string s = i.ToString();
                var d = new Data { Id = s, Text = s };
                dict.Add(d.Id, d);
                list.Add(d);
                keyd.Add(d);
            }

            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++)
            {
                foreach (Data d in dict.Values)
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var dictTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++)
            {
                foreach (Data d in keyd)
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var keydTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++)
            {
                foreach (Data d in list)
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var listTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Iterate whole collection");
            Console.WriteLine("Dict: " + dictTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Keyd: " + keydTime);
            Console.WriteLine("List: " + listTime);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 10)
                {
                    string s = i.ToString();
                    Data d = dict[s];
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            dictTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 1000; r++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 10)
                {
                    string s = i.ToString();
                    Data d = keyd[s];
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            keydTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 10)
                {
                    string s = i.ToString();
                    Data d = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == s);
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            listTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 100;

            Console.WriteLine("Keyed search collection");
            Console.WriteLine("Dict: " + dictTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Keyd: " + keydTime);
            Console.WriteLine("List: " + listTime);

        }
    }
```

}

UPDATE:

Comparison of Dictionary with KeyedCollection as suggested by @Blam.

The fastest method is iterating over an Array of KeyedCollection Items.

Note, however, that iterating over the dictionary values is faster than over the KeyedCollection without converting to an array.

Note that iterating over the dictionary values is much, much faster than over the dictionary collection.

```
 Iterate 1,000 times over collection of 10,000 items
   Dictionary Pair:   519 ms
 Dictionary Values:    95 ms
  Dict Val ToArray:    92 ms
   KeyedCollection:   141 ms
   KeyedC. ToArray:    17 ms
```

Timings are from a Windows console application (Release build). Here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace IterateCollections
{
    public class GUIDkeyCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<Guid, GUIDkey>
    {
        // This parameterless constructor calls the base class constructor 
        // that specifies a dictionary threshold of 0, so that the internal 
        // dictionary is created as soon as an item is added to the  
        // collection. 
        // 
        public GUIDkeyCollection() : base() { }

        // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden, 
        // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the 
        // keys from the items.  
        // 
        protected override Guid GetKeyForItem(GUIDkey item)
        {
            // In this example, the key is the part number. 
            return item.Key;
        }

        public GUIDkey[] ToArray()
        {
            return Items.ToArray();
        }

        //[Obsolete("Iterate using .ToArray()", true)]
        //public new IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException("Iterate using .ToArray()");
        //}
    }
    public class GUIDkey : Object
    {
        private Guid key;
        public Guid Key
        {
            get
            {
                return key;
            }
        }
        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            //Check for null and compare run-time types.
            if (obj == null || !(obj is GUIDkey)) return false;
            GUIDkey item = (GUIDkey)obj;
            return (Key == item.Key);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() { return Key.GetHashCode(); }
        public GUIDkey(Guid guid)
        {
            key = guid;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int itemCount = 10000;
            const int repetitions = 1000;
            const string resultFormat = "{0,18}: {1,5:D} ms";

            Console.WriteLine("Iterate {0:N0} times over collection of {1:N0} items", repetitions, itemCount);

            var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, GUIDkey>();
            var keyd = new GUIDkeyCollection();

            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                var d = new GUIDkey(Guid.NewGuid());
                dict.Add(d.Key, d);
                keyd.Add(d);
            }

            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            long time;

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, GUIDkey> w in dict)
                {
                    if (null == w.Value) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(resultFormat, "Dictionary Pair", time);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            {
                foreach (GUIDkey d in dict.Values)
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(resultFormat, "Dictionary Values", time);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            {
                foreach (GUIDkey d in dict.Values.ToArray())
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(resultFormat, "Dict Val ToArray", time);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            {
                foreach (GUIDkey d in keyd)
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(resultFormat, "KeyedCollection", time);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            {
                foreach (GUIDkey d in keyd.ToArray())
                {
                    if (null == d) throw new ApplicationException();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(resultFormat, "KeyedC. ToArray", time);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The second would be faster, most likely, as Dictionary values will be sparse.  List values, depending on the implementation, will probably be better.

Comment: You going for milliseconds shave in timing the application or there specific reason not to use optimized Linq queries ?

Comment: Premature micro optimization is evil.

Comment: I think they will be about the same in speed. But the difference would be marginal. I don't believe that this really is a performance problem in your application. You should attach a profiler to identify the real causes for slow performance.

Comment: Iterating through an array would be even faster. But unless your profiling shows this is a bottleneck, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Profiling has already been done and I'm considering converting from List<> to Dictionary<> for large data sets in a frequently used area of an ASP.NET web application. The List<> was used for both complete enumeration and keyed search using foreach with break when found.

Comment: Stated Key is GUID and yet you test on Int.ToString().  When I test collections based on stated key with proper implementations of OverRideGetHashCode and Equal then KeyedCollection wins and it is smaller than Dictionary as it does not repeat the key.  And another benefit is KeyedCollection preserves order and Dictionary does not.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow Assuming that every instance of Micro Optimization is premature optimization, is the root of all evil. Just because you read it somewhere does not make it true. For example I ended up here because I am iterating a dictionary.values about 7000 times per frame run with a minimum of 60 frames per second. And was too lazy to benchmark it myself. In game coding saving 2ms per frame can make or break meeting the required 60 frames per second or dropping well below 60 fps. I even have to micro optimize for GC collections. Assumptions are the root of all evil. Don't do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is relatively easy to check with a stopwatch:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var s = new List<object>();
for (int i =0 ; i != 10000000 ; i++) {
    d.Add(""+i, i);
    s.Add(i);
}
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
foreach(object o in d.Values) {
    if (o == null) throw new ApplicationException();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
foreach (object o in s) {
    if (o == null) throw new ApplicationException();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

This prints numbers that are reasonably close to each other:

```
Dict List
---- ----
 136  107
 139  108
 136  108
```

The `List` always wins, but the margins are not as large as one would expect, given the relative complexity of the two data structures.

Answer (score 6):

If you want lookup by key then Dictionary.
Dictionary lookup by key is very fast as that is what it is designed to do.

The difference in foreach will be minor.

If the key is also a property then consider KeyedCollection
[KeyedCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

> Provides the abstract base class for a collection whose keys are
>   embedded in the values.

As Servy commented pick the collection with the features you need
.NET has many collections.
[System.Collections Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035.aspx)

And if your objects have a natural key that can be represented as an Int32 then consider OverRide GetHashCode().

If your objects have a natural key of GUID then consider KeyedCollection and OverRide GetHashCode and Equals

And for seach on nonKey properties consider LINQ rather than ForEach with a break;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace IntIntKeyedCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Guid findGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
            GUIDkeyCollection gUIDkeyCollection = new GUIDkeyCollection();
            gUIDkeyCollection.Add(new GUIDkey(findGUID));
            gUIDkeyCollection.Add(new GUIDkey(Guid.NewGuid()));
            gUIDkeyCollection.Add(new GUIDkey(Guid.NewGuid()));
            GUIDkey findGUIDkey = gUIDkeyCollection[findGUID];  // lookup by key (behaves like a dict)
            Console.WriteLine(findGUIDkey.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(findGUIDkey.GetHashCode());
            Console.WriteLine(findGUID);
            Console.WriteLine(findGUID.GetHashCode());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public class GUIDkeyCollection : KeyedCollection<Guid, GUIDkey>
        {
            // This parameterless constructor calls the base class constructor 
            // that specifies a dictionary threshold of 0, so that the internal 
            // dictionary is created as soon as an item is added to the  
            // collection. 
            // 
            public GUIDkeyCollection() : base() { }

            // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden, 
            // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the 
            // keys from the items.  
            // 
            protected override Guid GetKeyForItem(GUIDkey item)
            {
                // In this example, the key is the part number. 
                return item.Key;
            }
        }
        public class GUIDkey : Object
        {
            private Guid key;
            public Guid Key
            {
                get
                {
                    return key;
                }
            }
            public override bool Equals(Object obj)
            {
                //Check for null and compare run-time types.
                if (obj == null || !(obj is GUIDkey)) return false;
                GUIDkey item = (GUIDkey)obj;
                return (Key == item.Key);
            }
            public override int GetHashCode() { return Key.GetHashCode(); }
            public GUIDkey(Guid guid)
            {
                key = guid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow The point of this answer is that you should use the collection type appropriate for you needs, and that since you're never in a position where both suit your needs exactly there's no need to compare their speed.  You use the code that is correct, rather than the code that is faster but doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: The key is a Guid and is a property of the object.

Comment: Then for sure consider a Keyed collection.

Comment: @Blam, have you timed KeyedCollection? I've edited my question with a sample problem and my results. Is there something I'm missing with KeyedCollection?

Comment: Yes you missed something.  You state the actual key is GUID.  Yet you test on String of Int - not the same!  I provided detail on KeyCollection with Key of GUID and OverRide GetHashCode and Equals that you totally ignore - and yes it matters.  And you don't even have the courtesy of a +1.

Comment: Thank you for following up. I changed the program to use the classes as you provided. I had misunderstood that GUIDkey was the data and not the key. The timing results, however, are the same as before unless a slight modification is made. What numbers do you see?


I have updated the question with the new source.  Notice that if the KeyedCollection Items are converted to an array prior to iteration, the time is much faster. I have decided to +1 your suggestion of KeyedCollection because I was able to make it faster using ToArray.

Comment: Well in this test is it very close on enumerate.  This is a web site - how often do you enumerate all the items in a list of 10000?   You dropped lookup.  I can imagine web site would do look ups.  To me you are making design conditions based on what you know how to test rather than actual application needs and performance bottle necks.  If you have a class with a natural key then it should OverRide GetHashCode and Equals.  If an object has a natural key then KeyCollection is my first choice.

Answer (score 4):

It's about the same time. Surely it won't be noticable once your process includes any code.

But why do you listen to random people from the internet? Test it!

The [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your test:

```
class speedtest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 10000000;
        Dictionary<string, object> valuesDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        List<object> valuesList = new List<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            valuesDict.Add(i.ToString(), i);
            valuesList.Add(i);
        }
        // valuesDict loaded with thousands of objects

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        foreach (object value in valuesDict.Values) { /* process */ }
        s.Stop();

        Stopwatch s2 = new Stopwatch();
        s2.Start();
        foreach (object value in valuesList) { /* process */ }
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Size {0}, Dictonary {1}ms, List {2}ms",size,s.ElapsedMilliseconds,s2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

Outputs:
Size 10000000, Dictonary 73ms, List 63ms
```

However you should also test if you have hashing collisions in your dictionary. They can give you a different outcome.

In cases of a real application, you have to consider the time spend creating, accessing and memory foot print of your structure.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, premature optimization yadda yadda. Use the right collection for the right scenario and only worry about speed if it becomes a problem.

Anyway, the only way to know is to measure. I made a quick and dirty test which populates a dictionary and a list with 30,000 objects and then iterates them 10,000 times. Results are:

Dictionary: 2683ms
List: 1955ms

So, it would seem that Dictionary.Values is slightly slower to enumerate for whatever reason.

Here is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    int i = 0;

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var list = new List<object>();

    for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        dict.Add(i.ToString(), foo);
        list.Add(foo);
    }

    var dictWatch = new Stopwatch();

    dictWatch.Start();

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        foreach (var foo in dict.Values) {}
    }

    dictWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: " + dictWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    var listWatch = new Stopwatch();
    listWatch.Start();

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        foreach (var foo in list) {}
    }

    listWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("List: " + listWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

class Foo {}
```