# Is there a .net core 3.1 alternative for a synchronised KeyedCollection<Tkey, TItem> (compatible with async/await)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, collections, async-await

I have an Asp.Net core 3.1 app and i'd like to use a keyedCollection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedkeyedcollection-2?view=netframework-4.8

This is the code for that list so far;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A collection of leases. Implements <see cref="KeyedCollection{TKey,TItem}"/> which is a dictionary-list hybrid.
    /// </summary>
    public class LeaseInfoCollection : KeyedCollection<Guid, LeaseInfo>
    {
        #region Construction and Destruction

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection()
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection(IEqualityComparer<Guid> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection(IEqualityComparer<Guid> comparer, int dictionaryCreationThreshold)
            : base(comparer, dictionaryCreationThreshold)
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides of KeyedCollection<string,LeaseInfo>

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override Guid GetKeyForItem(LeaseInfo item)
        {
            return item.LeaseId;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

As we can see the `LeaseId` of type `Guid` is embedded into the lease object. The problem is i'd like for this list to be:

1. Periodically gone through to remove items based on a condition
2. Insert new items relatively frequently
3. LookedUp and return items almost as frequent as 2.

Step 1 will most likely run on a thread time, 2 and 1 are all driven by Threadpool-tasks. Therefore i need some kind of synchronization mechanism for the list.

I can roll my own and perhaps do something with reader/write lock (thinking about using the asyncEx library) but i see versions of .net where there is also a `SynchronisedKeyedCollection`. However, i see no such version in .net core 3.1.

Therefore are there ready made alternatives for `KeyedCollection` i could use for .net core 3.1 that are compatible with `async-await`?

Comment: Does [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) work for you?

Comment: @Xerillio i don't really think so since the key is embedded into the item itself. I could extract that and duplicate it as a key for the dictionary but that is kind of what keyedcollection does for me.

Comment: To be honest I have a hard time seeing the benefits of a `KeyedCollection` over a `Dictionary`. Without having investigated the implementation in detail, it seems all operations except Add will perform worse than a `Dictionary`. I'm guessing this is why `KeyedCollection` hasn't made it to .NET Core. I have no substantial evidence for this though.

Comment: @Xerillio the benefites are not in the performance per se - but in the functionality of the keyedcollection. For me particularly, i have some objects that have an ID. this is embedded into the item - so keyedcollection makes sense here. Like all things software there are other advantages/disadvantages; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566657/dictionary-or-keyedcollection

Comment: True, my impression from your points (2 and 3) were that performance was also a key point though. If the only benefit you're interested in is that you don't need to care about finding the item's key outside of the collection, then I think you could solve that pretty easily through a custom class that wraps `Dictionary`/`ConcurrentDictionary`.