# Generic OrderedDictionary

Tags: c#

I'm currently using:

```
Dictionary<Guid, OrderedDictionary>
```

But I need to do this:

```
Dictionary<Guid, OrderedDictionary<Guid, User>>
```

I am spoiled with generics and without generics I keep forgetting what type of object is where in my code.

Is this possible to do somehow?

Note:  The inner dictionary items have to be ordered, that is why I tried using the `OrderedDictionary` but it doesn't seem to support generics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary)