# Are elements in a .NET's Dictionary sequential?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Say, if I create a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

dic.add("z1", val1);
dic.add("abc9", val2);
dic.add("abc8", val3);
dic.add("ABC1", val4);
```

So when I do:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MyClass> kvp in dic)
{
}
```

Am I guaranteed to have these values retrieved as such: "z1", "abc9", "abc8", "ABC1"?

And what if I first do this, will it be: "z1", "abc8", "ABC1"?

```
dic.Remove("abc9");
```

Comment: `Am I guaranteed to have these values retrieved as such: "z1", "abc9", "abc8", "ABC1"?` **NO**

Comment: Nope, though potentially confusing since dictionaries IRL are alphabetically of course :)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: Except for ideographic languages . . . :)

Comment: Trying it doesn't provide an answer to wether or not the feature is formally supported (and thus will remain supported in the future). Considering todays implementation can only falsify, not verify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is *No*.  Order is not guaranteed in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, nor should you count on order being maintained.

You might want to [check into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) `OrderedDictionary` instead.

Example:

```
OrderedDictionary d = new OrderedDictionary();

d.Add("01", "First");
d.Add("02", "Second");
d.Add("03", "Third");
d.Add("04", "Fourth");
d.Add("05", "Fifth");

for(int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++) // Print values in order
{
   Console.WriteLine(d[i]);
}
```

Note there's no generic `OrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` version for some odd reason.  However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary) has some hints on how to implement one.

Comment: Thanks. It's good that I asked first. `OrderedDictionary` seems like what I need. So what you're saying, is that if I replace `Dictionary` with `OrderedDictionary` in my code above, my assumption would hold true, yes?

Comment: @ahmd0 - Correct, however there doesn't *appear* to be a generic version of `OrderedDictionary` for some reason, so you'd have to cast each value when you access them.

Comment: No, it is not the same. Just verified it. The `foreach` loop like I showed above compiles but then crashes with `OrderedDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`. It must be changed to `foreach (DictionaryEntry de in dic){}`. Also those casts, like you pointed out, are quite annoying...

Comment: @ahmd0 - Yea, maybe best to write your own implementation. Or, Jon Skeet's suggestion of having a `Dictionary<>` plus a `List<>` to track order.

Answer (score 6):

No. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its
>   key. **The order in which the items are returned is undefined**.

You may want to look at the [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class if you want more control over the iteration order.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I guaranteed to have these values retrieved as such: "z1", "abc9", "abc8", "ABC1"?

Absolutely not. Always treat `Dictionary<,>` as an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs. Even though *as an implementation detail* you'll generally see them in insertion order if you only ever add values, you should *not* rely on this.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. **The order in which the items are returned is undefined.**

(Emphasis mine.)

If you need a particular order, you should use a different collection - potentially in conjunction with a dictionary, if you *also* need to be able to fetch by key. (It's not entirely uncommon to maintain an `IList<TKey>` as well as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for example.)

Comment: Jon; if you never remove or manipulate the Dictionary, only add items, the underlying implementation seems to suggest they would be in order since it is an an array of entries. Would that be correct? I've gone over this question previously and haven't been able to break this premise!

Comment: @AllanElder: Yes, that's what the *current* implementation does. But you should never rely on that.

Comment: @AllanElder - Many of bugs have been the result of *assuming* a behavior will never change.  If sort order is not guaranteed, sort order is not guaranteed.  For all we know, .NET 6.0 or .NET 12.0 might completely rewrite `Dictionary<>` causing incompatibilities with poorly written code years down the road.  By that time, the original authors are probably long gone, leaving some poor guy to clean up the mess (yes, I've been that poor guy).

Comment: @MikeChristensen: While some people may think .NET already has too many collections, I would have like to have seen .NET include more "add-only" collections, since such collections can often--for minimal added cost--offer guarantees that would be expensive in collections that allowed more varied mutations.  For example, maintaining insertion order in a dictionary where nothing is ever deleted is cheap; maintaining it in the presence of deletions is not.  Thread-safety is also much cheaper in add-only collections than in collections which allow other mutations.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee of elements order. Also, it can be different depending on actual implementation of IDictionary<...> interface.