# Can a SortedList<>/SortedDictionary<> with a properly implemented comparer be used to guarantee insertion order?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

If the goal is to create a generic **read-only** dictionary that preserves insertion order, can  SortedList<,> or SortedDictionary<,> be realiably used with an IComparer<> that attempts to maintain insertion order by doing something similar to the following?

```
class OrderedComparer<T> : IComparer<M>
{
    public int Compare(M x, M y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y) ? 0 : -1;//or 1
    }
}
SortedList<M> orderedList = new SortedList<M>(new OrderedComparer<T>());
```

(It's interesting that in the case of SortedDictionary, the above method need to return 0 or 1 in order to prevent the elements from being sorted in the reverse insertion order).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? List<> and Queue<> both list items in the order they were added.

Comment: @n8wrl *the goal is to create a generic read-only dictionary*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comparer must obey the law

```
Compare(a, b) == -Compare(b, a) //assuming only possible values are -1, 0, 1
```

This is the [symmetry property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your sample code does not obey it. Therefore the BCL collections do not give you any guarantee at all. You have violated the documented contract.

You can't do this.

Instead, you could add a new field to `M` where you store the insertion order as an `int`. You can then use that field in the comparer.

Comment: Important note: The correct "law" would be `Compare(a,b) > 0 == Compare(b,a) < 0 && (Compare(a,b) == 0) == (Compare(b,a) == 0) && Compare(a,b) < 0 == Compare(b,a) > 0` The one stated in the answer is only a simplified form when you only have the possible outputs of -1, 0, 1.

Comment: Yeah I was too lazy to type this... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That `Compare` implementation doesn't follow the [rules of symmetry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it should. That's not the right way to go about this.

For a list ordered by insertion order, simply use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the implementation. With a [`Dictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), on the other hand, "The order in which the items are returned is undefined." You could make your own [`IDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation that uses these two classes together to do what you're trying to do.

```
public class MyInsertionOrderDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private List<TKey> keysList;
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict;

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (TKey key in keysList)
        {
            TValue value = dict[key];
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
        }
    }

    // TODO implement interface
    // when adding:
    // keysList.Add(key);
    // dict.Add(key, value);

    // when removing:
    // keysList.Remove(key);
    // dict.Remove(key);

    // you could also implement an indexer property like
    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> this[int index] { get { ... } }
}
```

This class is externally very similar to the [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, but is generic. There are [other generic implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844528/781792) out there.

Comment: Good idea, but the only change I would do is only use a `OrderedDictionary` instead of a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and a `List<TValue>` and just do the necessary casting when you call any method that returns `object` from the internal collection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, that's another option. However, that (unlike using generics directly) will mean that boxing, unboxing, and casting will happen at runtime. While it probably won't be a big issue, that does have a small performance hit, especially for `struct`s (e.g. `int`).

Answer (score 0):

There's no question about whether you **should** do such an horrible thing. You should definitely not, for all kinds of perfectly good reasons, like:

- Don't use sorted containers for unsorted data
- This is not how you use a comparer
- Avoid depending on implementation details of libraries you don't own

Now, to actually know whether you **can** preserve insertion order in a SortedList by hacking the comparer, there is only one way: look at the implementation. Decompile the bytecode, and see if it would work.

Turns out, `SortedList` uses a binary search, and `SortedDictionary` uses a red-black tree.

Fooling the binary search is easy. The comparer is only used for comparing new items (if you don't remove anything). Always return either 1 or -1, I always forget which, and you have an unsorted list.

For the red-black tree, I'm not sure whether the same trick works. I don't remember if that kind of tree has to use the comparer when it rebalances itself. If it does, the inability of your comparer to provide a meaningful result would lead you to runtime errors probably, or at best, loss of complexity guarantees. But maybe it's actually fine. Except that you will still get a maximum amount of rebalancing, I think.