# Multidimensional generic collection with position indexer

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, .net-4.5

Not sure if the title is properly worded but basically I am trying to load all the file names of text files in a given directory, then loading the lines of text from each file, all into one collection.

I would hope to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> db = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>;
db.Add("c:\text1.txt", new List<string>(new string[]{"line1","line2","line3"}));
```

And then to access it using `db[0]`

Is there any kind of collection to do this, or can you all recommend a different way of doing it?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, since dictionaries are unordered by default (items are stored in buckets, which depends on key hash code, the order of items doesn't matter), you have two options:

- use ordered version of dictionary-like collection (see [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`KeyedCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary));
- use any ordered collection, like `List<Tuple<string, List<string>>>`, but this disallows to search by key.

Comment: @blizz: `Tuple<...>` here is just a sample container to wrap a file name and its lines. You could use your own class as well, if `Tuple<...>` doesn't fit your needs.