# Organizing dictionary based on class elements

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I have a program where I'm adding objects to a dictionary. The dictionary is set up with an int and my custom 'Ship' class. The problem is I need to organize the ships by a variable in the class.

The ship class is -

```
public class Ship
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int Engine { get; set; }
    public int Shield { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string ShipClass { get; set; }

    public Ship(string name, int attack, int engine, int shield, string team, string shipClass)
    {
        Name = name;
        Attack = attack;
        Engine = engine;
        Shield = shield;
        Team = team;
        ShipClass = shipClass;
    }
}
```

And I need to organize

```
Dictionary<int,Ship> ShipList = new Dictionary<int,Ship>();
```

by ShipList[i].Engine where i goes down through each ship I have.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Dictionary` is unordered, so there's no sense in trying to sort the dictionary and keep it in a dictionary. This will give you a `List` of key/value (int/Ship) pairs, ordered by `Engine`:

```
var orderedPairs = ShipList.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Engine).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you with an ordered collection. Note if you don't need to sort all of the ships, you should probably limit this with a where clause to reduce the overhead of sorting all the ships.

```
ShipList.Values.OrderBy(s => s.Attack);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure actual dictionary is ordered, you would need to use SortedDictionary class instead and supply your own IComparer. Standard Dictionary doesn't support sorting by key.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) or a [generic equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary)