# How to enable C# 6.0 feature in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c#-6.0

I was going through the latest features introduced in C# 6.0 and just followed an example of auto property initializer,

```
class NewSample
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

but my IDE did not recognize the syntax.

I am wondering how I could enable C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2013. The Target framework I am using is 4.5.1.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible in 2013. Look into VS 14 CTP instead or the VS 2015 preview.

Comment: Well, you'd need the latest compiler, which is not part of VS 2013, so I don't think that's possible.

Comment: well, i am just looking to find out whether ms releases any update or not

Comment: That version is outdated. Don't use it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado What does 'that' mean in "that version is outdated"? 4.5.1, VS2013, or VS2014CTP?

Comment: VS2013 support was just a preview of a preview. The latest VS2015 preview is the closest to the final version of C#6.0.

Comment: "Roslyn is no longer available for Visual Studio 2013." at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn :(

Comment: Can you please update the answer on this question to @Deef

Comment: Good for VS 2013! ... that syntax is hideous.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Information for obsoleted prerelease software:

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) it's just a install and go for Visual Studio 2013:

> In fact, installing the C# 6.0 compiler from this release involves little more than installing a Visual Studio 2013 extension, which in turn updates the MSBuild target files.

So just get the files from https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn and you are ready to go.

**You do have to know it is an outdated version of the specs implemented there, since they no longer update the package for Visual Studio 2013**:

> You can also try April's End User Preview, which installs on top of Visual Studio 2013.
> (note: this VS 2013 preview is quite out of date, and is no longer updated)

So if you do want to use the latest version, you have to download the [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).

Comment: yeah same line which i read. Just thinking of getting vs 2015 preview

Comment: unfortunatily, the end user preview for vs 2013 has been closed :(

Comment: The preview is still available here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793

Comment: It is. But it isn't updated any more. See the last update date.

Comment: Just to make sure, there is no a supported way to write in C# 6 using VS 2013? Do I have to use VS 2015?

Comment: That is correct. @vorou There is no recent version of the preview for VS 2013.

Comment: Actually, these is a way (see my answer). But it's different than what you could do months ago before the final release.

Comment: none of the solutions in this topic or other similar topics helped me. so the only work around is moving to VS 2015 I guess.

Comment: I was having this problem IN VS2015 and it appears the issue was my CSPROJ files pointing to an old ToolsVersion and since I had that old .NET version it would compile using it. This is why it worked for others, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 176):

Under VS2013 you can install the new compilers into the project as a **nuget package**. That way you don't need VS2015 or an updated build server.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

The package allows you to use/build C# 6.0 code/syntax. Because VS2013 doesn't natively recognize the new C# 6.0 syntax, *it will show errors in the code editor window although it will build fine*.

Using Resharper, you'll get squiggly lines on C# 6 features, but the bulb gives you the option to 'Enable C# 6.0 support for this project' (setting saved to .DotSettings).

As mentioned by @stimpy77: for support in **MVC Razor views** you'll need an extra [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/) (for those that don't read the comments)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

If you want full C# 6.0 support, you'll need to install VS2015.

Comment: I see autoinitialized props works, however primary constructor does not

Comment: Yes. This is a working solution if you don't have the option go to VS2015. It will allow you to build, but it is quite hard with a IDE they doesn't really work. My opinion: use VS2015. It was built for the job.

Comment: Primary constructors were actually removed from the final release.  That's why they don't work.

Comment: This is a good backup in cases of emergency problems with VS 2015, as we have: Azure SDK refuses to update credentials, so Server/Cloud Explorers are completely dead.

Comment: Just want to point out for anyone wanting to use C#6 in Razor in an MVC5 project, looks like that's a separate NuGet package, and required even if you're using VS2015. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30832849/11398

Comment: Great solution for enterprise environments where you have some developers testing VS2015 and others still on VS2013.

Comment: It works (as in you can compile), however VS2013 still shows errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796001/c6-error-messages-on-vs2013-despite-using-microsoft-net-compilers-nuget-package

Comment: Works very nice! Is there also a way to install that package machine-wide?

Comment: he he he. This was cool. Compiler shows errors in advance but compiles successfully when actually compiled. What a hack to start a weekend morning!

Comment: Note that the **build time will be increased for VS 2015 users** after adding Microsoft.Net.Compilers package

Comment: **it will show errors in the code editor window although it will build fine.** Just felt the need to point it again. Great answer!

Comment: This didn't work for me on VS 2013. I had to install an older version of there is an answer by SteveCinq that worked, basically installing older version of compiler. I'm not sure what the negative consequences might be- but I only needed to compile this one program.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the answers here were written prior to *Roslyn* (the open-source .NET C# and VB compilers) moving to .NET 4.6. So they won't help you if your project targets, say, 4.5.2 as mine did (inherited and can't be changed).

But you can grab a previous version of *Roslyn* from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers and install that instead of the latest version. I used 1.3.2. (I tried 2.0.1 - which appears to be the last version that runs on .NET 4.5 - but I couldn't get it to compile*.) Run this from the Package Manager console in VS 2013:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.3.2
```

Then restart Visual Studio. I had a couple of problems initially; you need to set the C# version back to *default* (C#6.0 doesn't appear in the version list but seems to have been made the default), then clean, save, restart VS and recompile.

Interestingly, I didn't have any IntelliSense errors due to the C#6.0 features used in the code (which were the reason for wanting C#6.0 in the first place).

* version 2.0.1 threw error *The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.*

**UPDATE** One thing I've noticed since posting this answer is that if you change any code during debug ("Edit and Continue"), you'll like find that your C#6.0 code will suddenly show as errors in what seems to revert to a pre-C#6.0 environment. This requires a restart of your debug session. VERY annoying especially for web applications.

Comment: @RichBianco That's great - thanks for the feedback and up-vote.  Personally, I can't understand why v2.0.1 doesn't work. If anyone has any clues about this - as in, getting rid of the error I reported - please post your fix.

Answer (score 4):

It worth mentioning that the **build time will be increased for VS 2015 users after**:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

Those who are using VS 2015 and have to keep this package in their projects **can fix increased build time**.

Edit file `packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.2.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` and clean it up. The file should look like:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
</Project>
```

Doing so forces a project to be built as it was before adding `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use full C# 6.0 features in Visual Studio 2013 if you have Resharper.
You have to enable Resharper Build and voilá!
In Resharper Options -> Build  - enable Resharper Build and in "Use MSBuild.exe version" choose "Latest Installed"

This way Resharper is going to build your C# 6.0 Projects and will also not underline C# 6.0 code as invalid.

I am also using this although I have Visual Studio 2015 because:

1. Unit Tests in Resharper don't work for me with Visual Studio 2015 for some reason
2. VS 2015 uses a lot more memory than VS 2013.

I am putting this here, as I was looking for a solution for this problem for some time now and maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there's some misunderstanding. So, instead of trying to patch VS2013 here's and answer from a Microsoft guy: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49ba9a67-d26a-4b21-80ef-caeb081b878e/will-c-60-ever-be-supported-by-vs-2013?forum=roslyn

So, please, read it and install VS2015.

Comment: the link gives me 'not authorized' even after ms login. Of course, install VS2015 or later is a £XXX,000s expense in some settings.