# How do I handle a C# codebase being edited in both VS 2013 and VS2015 with regards to the breaking change of "using static" in C# 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I have a C# codebase which is being edited in both VS 2013 and VS 2015 CTP 6.  With CTP 6 has come C# v6 which requires "using static" on some imports.

Is there a way in which I can determine which version (either VS or C#) is being used such that I can use a preprocessor directive to use either "using" or "using static"?

e.g.

```
#if CS6
   using static ...
#else
   using ...
#endif
```

A preprocessor directive is my initial thought.  If there is another way to do this I am all ears.

Comment: I was writing an answer then I reread your question and saw you said "*With CTP 6 has come C# v6 which requires "using static"*" Is it the case that a static `using` is **required** to use CTP6 and you want to be able to concurrently develop in C#5 and C#6 CTP6, or that you **want** the syntactic sugar of static `using`s **and** to concurrently develop in C#5 and C#6 CTP6? I ask because [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) says "*it’s possible to eliminate an explicit reference to the type when invoking a static method*" which leads me to think the latter.

Comment: Hi Wai Ha Lee.  I think it is the former case.  Basically when I build in C# 5 - no problem.  When I build in C# 6 the build fails because it wants "using static" - in this case for System.Environment.

Comment: Out of interest, which member of `Environment` is causing the error?

Comment: It is the GetFolderPath() method.  I appreciate your help :o)

Comment: Hmm. Does calling [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.100).aspx) not work when compiling as C#6 CTP6?

Comment: LOL. The blinding flash of the obvious that went flying past me.  It works :o)  Thanks Wai Ha Lee.

Comment: No problem. :) I have to admit, I was rather curious as to why this was causing a problem for you.

Comment: Would you reply with an answer so that I can give you credit for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The static `using` shouldn't be *required*; it is syntactic sugar that has been added to C# 6.0. You should **always** be able to specify the fully qualified name of a static method to call it, e.g. instead of

```
using System.Environment;

// class and method declaration elided

var path = GetFolderPath(...);
```

You could always have

```
// no static using here!

// class and method declaration elided

var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(...);
```

or, if you don't have a class of your own called `System` (why would you do that?):

```
// still no static using here!
using System;

// class and method declaration elided

var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a breaking change if it doesn't break previously compilable code. Since there weren't static imports in C# before 6.0, this isn't a breaking change.

It is also not required. That would be a real breaking change.

If you want to work on a code base simultaneously with Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015, you'll have to use the maximum common denominator which is C# 5.0.

Comment: Hi Paulo.  Thanks for the info.  I have a question though.  "It is also not required".  I have heard this once before, but there is some piece of info I am missing here.  In this particular instance I am using the GetFolderPath method in System.Environment.  In C# 6, if I do not use either "using static System.Environment" or within the code use "System.Environment.GetFolderPath" I get a build error.  Is there a configuration piece or some other such info I am missing?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx "Environment.GetFolderPath Method")? What exactly is the build error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Paulo.  Yes, System.Environment.GetFolderPath is indeed the function in question.  The error I am getting is this:

    Error CS0138 A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Environment' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead.

Thanks again for your help on this one.

Comment: That's because your using directive looks like this: `using System.Environment`. To import a class instead of a namespace, `C#-6.0` requires the using directive to be: `using static System.Environment` But that will be invalida prior to `C#-6.0'. You should use `using System;` and `Environment.GetFolderPath()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling C# 6.0 support in Visual Studio 2013 by following the instructions described here: [How to enable C# 6.0 feature in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)

I have not tested it though.

Comment: I've used this feature just fine with VS2013