# Auto-property initializers won't work?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to use [auto-property initializers](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status), like so:

```
class Class1
{
    public string Auth { get; set; } = "BlahBlah";
}
```

However, when I build, I get the following error:

> Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

This is in Visual Studio 2013, using Target Framework .NET 4.6 (which is the version which introduced auto-property initializers).

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: This is a feature of C# 6, not .NET Framework.

Comment: It looks like there's an outdated version of an extension that implements some C# 6 features for VS 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013  If you want the full compiler, you'll have to upgrade to VS 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be targeting .NET 4.6 but auto-initializers is a C# 6 feature rather than a feature of the Framework.