# Importing project to xamarin error

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

The app dev company that I recently hired sent me a folder containing all of the source code to my app (developed in Xamarin). I opened the .sln file in Visual Studio (after installing Xamarin) to find that it does not compile. It gives the errors

```
"; expected" 

"Unexpected character '$'"

"Invalid token ')'".
```

These errors seem to indicate I might be missing a library or some necessary file for Xamarin to compile my app.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like the code is corrupted or not even valid C#.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013. I read somewhere that 2015 is required for C# 6.0? Can anyone confirm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013