# Using $ as a prefix when declaring a string

Tags: c#

I cannot compile the following code

```
var baseUrl = $"http://{endPoint}/";
```

I got this code from a github project, and i guess the $-sign tells the compiler to use the value of the attribute(and even do methods that return a string).

I have been looking online, but i cant seem to find anything but @"String" to ignore escape characters.

Comment: The `$` is for string interpolation, and is a C#6 feature. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  You'll need to be using VS 2015 for C# 6.

Comment: Note that if you wish to use C# 6 [you need Visual Studio 2015, or an extension on Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27093908/993547).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$` does string interpolation, which is a C# 6 feature.

It's the equivalent of doing this:

```
var baseUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/", endPoint);
```

You can read more about it [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx).

If it does not compile for you, it's probably because you are using a version of Visual Studio that does not support C#6 features.

Comment: Oké, I did not know the term 'interpolation' making googling quite ineffective :). I am working in an older version of visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` string prefix is only available in C# 6. To change your targeted C# version in Visual Studio, go to your project properties → *Build* → *Advanced...* → *Language Version*, and select *C# 6.0* .

Note that C# 6 is only supported in VS 2015 by default.

Comment: Not entirely true. [Works in VS 2013 too.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27093908/993547)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not out of the box, though - you have to install an extension for that.