# C# 6 error messages on VS2013 despite using Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, c#-6.0

Over half of our 50 man development team still uses Visual Studio 2013. Despite this, we would like to use C# 6. So we tried using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010632/3997704.

Compilation with `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` works fine, as does our CI environment. However, Visual Studio shows a lot of errors in the Error List related to C# 6 features. I tried getting rid of the errors by using clean solution, rebuild, restarting Visual Studio and clearing ReSharper caches but none worked.

Comment: Well, the answer you linked to explicitly says this is going to happen. I don't think there's a way to fix that.

Comment: Well, that's one way to interpret "The editor will be thrown off however by these new features." I would have wanted that answer to state this problem before spending time on it since it is not a solution if you get thousands of errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though you install the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package in your project, Visual Studio still uses the C# 5 compiler for the editor. That's why it compiles the C# 6 code, but the editor doesn't understand it. Unfortunately, there is no way to change the compiler editor uses and [probably never will be](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49ba9a67-d26a-4b21-80ef-caeb081b878e/will-c-60-ever-be-supported-by-vs-2013?forum=roslyn).

So the only way for the full C# 6 support is to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015.