# Invalid token in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have problem with my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace popo
{
    public class Human
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Login: ");
            public string LogInput = Console.Read();
            if(LogInput=="ADMIN")
            {
                System.Console.Write("Password: ");
                public string PassInput = Console.Read();
                if(PassInput == "ADMIN")
                {
                    System.Console.Write("L");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Console.Write("O");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Console.Write("G");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Console.Write("G");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Console.Write("E");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Console.Write("D");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When Im trying to compile it, compiler says:

> Mm.cs(10,38): error CS1513: } expected
> Mm.cs(12,13): error CS1519: Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> Mm.cs(12,24): error CS1519: Invalid token '==' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> Mm.cs(14,37): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Post your code as `code text`, not images.

Comment: Im not able to do that cause then it's mostly code and i can't send it,

Comment: Just copy and paste the text shown in your images into this question. If there needs to be more text, then please better describe your problem using more non-code words.

Comment: fixed. sorry im new here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179921/invalid-token-in-class-struct-or-interface-member-declaration-c-sharp)

Comment: No. first error is on line 10 "} expected" . 10th line is console.writeline. and when im removing 10th line it says that } is expected in 9

Comment: Remove `public` in the declaration of `LogInput` and `PassInput`, and also replace `Console.Read()` by `Console.ReadLine()`. That is, you should have `string LogInput = Console.ReadLine();` and `string PassInput = Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: Don't forget to thank the person who answered by upvoting and accepting their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Main()` function, the local variables `LogInput` and `PassInput` must be declared without the `public` keyword. Also, replace `Console.Read()` by `Console.ReadLine()`. Thus your `Main()` should look like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Login: ");
    string LogInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if(LogInput=="ADMIN")
    {
        System.Console.Write("Password: ");
        string PassInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if(PassInput == "ADMIN")
        {
           // further as you had it...
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q8cyzm).