# Is this a valid syntax in C# .NET 4.6.2

Tags: c#, syntax, setter

```
public class MyClass
{

    public string DeviceCommands { get; set; } = "DeviceCommands";
}
```

I have 30 errors on this kind of lines...

Comment: this syntax is valid in C#6, you can compile it in many .net targets, 4.6 is one of them

Comment: To add C# 6 to VS2013 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010632/1544886

Answer (score 5):

.NET 4.6.2 is a framework version, not a language version. To be able to do that line you must be using C# 6 or newer. If you are compiling with C# 6 you would be allowed to use that syntax in a .NET 2.0 project.

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 or newer you are using C# 6 or newer.

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 and are still getting errors there is some other problem with your code that you are not showing us.

**UPDATE:**

If you are using VS2015 and are getting a error that says

> **Error CS8026**: Feature 'auto property initializer' is not available in C# 5.  Please use language version 6 or greater.

That means in your project properties -> Build -> Advanced screen you set the language version manually to 5 or lower instead of default.

[image]

Setting it back to `default` will fix the problem.

Comment: I am using VS2013 and .NET 4.6.2 is set in the project settings - I see now that in a previous project version it was compiling but now it is not...and can't find any apparent reason...

Comment: ***"I am using VS2013..."*** That is your problem. You are using C# 5 because you are using VS2013, you need to open the project in VS2015 to be able to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have are Auto Property Initializers.

It has nothing to do with the .NET Version. It is a language feature from `C# 6.0`.

You need the the [roslyn compiler plattform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27093908/2441442) to make this work.

If you can not support `C# 6.0`, you could do it the old way:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string DeviceCommands { get; set; };

    public MyClass()
    {
        DeviceCommands = "DeviceCommands";
    }
}
```