# C# using static directive not valid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, using-directives

[image]

Wondering why the "using static" is not functional in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Guy you can in c#6 and above

Comment: Because it was only introduced with VS2015

Comment: But why the tutorial in the link worked?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: That link points at VS2015 documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need a minimum of VS 2015 to use c# 6 features.

You also need to ensure that c#6 is enabled in the `Language version` property of the project.

Answer (score 0):

"using static" feature was introduced in C# 6.0. 
How to enable C# 6.0 features in Visual Studio 2013 is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)