# public override string extension => "test" ; this code work in VS2017 but gives error(; expected) in vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

```
public override string teststr => "test";
```

This code works fine in Visual studio 2015 and VS2017 but throws the following error in Visual Studio 2013:

> ; expected

Comment: If my answer is useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an expression bodied property - they are only supported in C# 6.0 or higher.

VS2013 doesn't support C# 6.0 by default, so it won't be able to compile that code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013) discusses how to add support for C# 6.0 to VS2013. But is you're using expression bodied properties you really should learn about them more, and what language versions support them.

The expression bodied syntax is equivalent to:

```
public override string teststr
{
    get
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

for earlier versions of C#.

Comment: thanks dear, can i have another way to make that work in 2013

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Another way? Other than installing C# 6 support?

Comment: can i have another way to assign,rather than using "=>"

Comment: I have updated my answer, but you seem to have very little understanding of C#. Instead of asking questions on SO that are extremely easy to find out just by searching on google, spend some time actually learning the language.