# Getting error on activity.CreateReply in Microsoft bot application

Tags: c#, botframework

I have just started to learn the Microsoft chat bot framework. I have added a Bot application in my VS 2013 professional. I am trying to create the basic chat bot application to calculate the length of the string passed to the bot. But i am getting the error on the CreateReply method as below:

```
 if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            int  length = (activity.Text ?? String.Empty).Length;
            Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"your text {acivity.Text} have {lenght} characters");
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
```

The above code does not recognize the "$" in CreateReply method.

[image: code snippet]

[image: error list]

I am using MS VS Professional 2013

Microsoft.Bot.Builder - 3.9.0.0

Please help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using C# 6.0? $ as a string formatter didn't exist before that.

Comment: While creating Bot Application in VS, I have selected .NET Framework 4.6 from the dropdownlist and started working on it. VS studio version I am using is  MS VS Professional 2013.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: can you used c# 6.0 in VS13?

Comment: I dont know, if we can use c# 6.0 in VS2013. I have updated the VS to 2015. Now, I am not getting any error as I mentioned above.