# Invalid tokens when setting properties inline for .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net

I believe this functionality was added to 4.6. My project is using this framework for a targeted version but it's throwing simple illegal tokens errors.

```
public String Text {get; set;} = "This is a test";
```

I am wondering if there is anything else I am missing that I need to modify to make my project compliant.

Thank you

Comment: Same error, unfortunately.

Comment: It's a C# 6 feature. What version of Visual Studio is this?

Comment: This is Visual Studio version 2013.

Comment: public String text { get; set; } = "This is a test"; using vs2015

Answer (score 2):

You need Visual Studio 2015 or later. 
Or you can try to install extensions for VS2013. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013) for more details.

Comment: What could be done to change this: List<String> list { get; set; } = new List<String>(); How could I make this compliant for VS13?

Comment: @Arrayoob Initialize the property in the constructor instead.