# Issue compiling EPPlus in VS 2013

Tags: c#, compilation, epplus

Trying to use EPPLus for the first time.

I downloaded it from https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus and I get errors while trying to compile the solutions on Visual Studio 2013.

The first error I get on the line

```
public IEnumerable<System.DateTime> AdditionalDates => _holidayDates;
```

where `;` is expected in the place of the operator `=>`

Thank you in advance for helping me finding my mistake.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013  , or use Visual Studion 2015 or newer. 

This is about 'Auto-Property Initializers' from C# 6, and C# is not supported by VS 2013 from the box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C# 6.0 feature in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: I would encourage using Nuget for dependencies, that way you would minimize the chances of adding incompatible versions. EPPlus is in the Nuget package list https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/