# $ (dollar sign) string in C# not working in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dollar-sign

Why can't I use the dollar sign `$` in `Console.WriteLine()`?
I know that I use it for using the C# code in `{}` but it doesn't work and I don't know why? My code is:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Name is : {}");
```

but Visual Studio gives me some error

> Error 1   Unexpected character '$
> Error 2   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I use Visual Studio 2013, I have this problem in this version but in version 2019 I don't have this problem. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: That string formatting shorthand became available in VS 2016. You're using quite an extremely old and deprecated VS version

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yeah i think it's because  I use the old version of visual studio

Comment: I reopened this question. The linked duplicate asked "what is a $ string" -- the OP clearly understands what the feature is, but they are asking *why it doesn't work*, which was not answered there.

Comment: You need support for C# 6 features in the tools you use. Once you have that, expect something like **error CS1733: Expected expression** because you leave the braces empty, `$"Name is : {}"`.

Answer (score 4):

A $-prefixed string is an [*interpolated string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which was added to the language in C# v6.

Visual Studio 2013 supports C# v6, but only as an optional feature:
[How to enable C# 6.0 feature in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013)