# Get the last item in an ordered dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm trying to get the last item in my ordered dictionary but it doesn't have the nice LINQ functions like a normal dictionary does such as `.First()` `.Last()`

I was just wondering if anyone knew how I could do this?

Comment: Not sure why this is being down voted, It's a fair question.

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow you will see the prompt “This question does not show any research effort”. Whether it's “fair” or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Possibly relevant or useful: [No generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2629027).

Answer (score 2):

The [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) does not implement the ***generic*** interface `IEnumerable<>`, and therefore the extension methods you mention do not apply.

You can use `.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` first. It can be used because it is based on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. It returns a generic `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>`, so you can use `.Last()` on that.

But it may be better to use a "newer" collection type.

Comment: How do I access the .Key and .Value on this? I only have .Values??

Comment: Never mind, after casting it as DictionaryEntry it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does casting to `DictionaryEntry` still guarantee sort order?

Comment: @reubano, Yes, it is guaranteed that `.Cast<TResult>()` will yield the items (strongly typed as `TResult`) in exactly the same order as the `source` (i.e. the underlying instance of the nongeneric `IEnumerable` type) does. It does so _lazily_ (documentation "This method is implemented by using deferred execution"). If you look at the source code for `Cast<TResult>()`, you see that the method is essentially a call to a private iterator method (i.e. a method whose body uses `yield return`) that looks like this: `{ foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj; }`