# Is there a an easier way to initialize a List<KeyValuePair<T, U>>, like a Dictionary<T, U>?

Tags: c#, .net

Actually I need something like `List<KeyValuePair<T, U>>` but I want to be able to initialize it like dictionary (i.e. without writing `new KeyValuePair` every time). Like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "key1", "value1"}, 
    { "key2", "value2"}
};
```

Comment: Actually, your goal appears to be a Dictionary, not a list, that preserves insertion order.  That is, a dictionary whose elements are 
sorted on insertion order, rather than their natural order.  Is this correct?

Comment: Nope, I just want dictionary-like initialization. Jon's answer is exactly what I need. Bad that I have do define new type though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out .NET *does* have a combination list/dictionary type already: [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx). Unfortunately this is a non-generic type, making it rather less attractive in my view. However, it retains the insertion order if you just call `Add` repeatedly.

It's a little strange as calling `Add` does *not* affect entries where a key already exists, whereas using the indexer to add a key/value pair will overwrite a previous association. Basically it doesn't seem like a terribly nice API, and I would personally still avoid it unless your use case *exactly* matches its behaviour.

---

No, .NET doesn't have any insertion-order-preserving dictionaries. You could always write your own list-based type with the relevant `Add` method. This might even be one of the few places I'd consider extending an existing type:

```
public class KeyValueList<TKey, TValue> : List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var list = new KeyValueList<string, string>
{
    { "key1", "value1"}, 
    { "key2", "value2"}
};
```

An alternative is to use composition, but my *gut feeling* is that this is a reasonable use of inheritance. I can't place why I'm happy in this case but not usually, mind you...

Comment: Of course, that will upset the code analysis with [CA1002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx) nor does it implement `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: @Rowland: Do you mean on the `KeyValueList` type itself? You could always suppress the warning. You may well not want to expose a *property* (etc) of type KeyValueList of course.

Comment: @Rowland: It's not at all clear that the OP really wants a dictionary - he wants to be able to *initialize* it like a dictionary, but from the start of the question: "Actually I need something like a List<...>"

Comment: Don't you have to use the syntax Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));?

Comment: @JJS: Nope - collection initializers are wonderful things. They'll look for appropriate `Add` methods; in this case `Add(key, value)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, how do I avoid the compiler error CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments in the Add method?

Comment: @JJS: You shouldn't have to - if you provide two arguments in braces, it should just find the right overload. If you're having problems, I suggest you ask a new, full question.

Comment: -1. .NET has [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)

Comment: @JonSkeet canceled vote. This question turns out to be the exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396718/generic-key-value-pair-collection-in-that-preserves-insertion-order

Comment: @nawfal: I'm not sure it *is* an exact duplicate really - after all, this question explicitly states that what's *really* required is a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` rather than a real dictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you're right. Often question title and description are worded wrongly. I went by former.

Answer (score 4):

Because you do not have a dictionary you cannot use a dictionary initiailzer. You have a list so you could use a list initializer which will be the closest you could get:

```
var l = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value2"),
};
```

Here's the minimum requirement for you to use dictionary initializer: the class must implement `IEnumerable` and the class must have a public method `Add` which takes 2 arguments (where the first argument represents the key and the second argument the value). So you could write a custom class which satisfies those requirements and you will be able to use the syntax you have shown in your question.

Comment: Up-voted because I'm more than willing to create a List<T> descendant with an extra Add method just to get the syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have typed works fine - further to Mads Togersen's [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx) about the implementation of collection initialisers, the compiler maps the brace-delimited entries (`{"key1", "value1"}` above) to an Add method on the collection with the same signature - in this case [Dictionary.Add(TKey, TValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx).

Comment: But it doesn't preserve insertion order, which is what the OP wants.