# EntityFramework add rows in the default order

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insertion order of multiple records in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521057/insertion-order-of-multiple-records-in-entity-framework)

I have a Table purchased objects, `Purchase(ID_PUR,Name,Quantity,...)` where `ID_PUR` is an identity(1,1) so when I add a purchase to my entity `Context.Purchases` it sorts the objects randomly !!!,

If I save `Context.SaveChanges()` after each `.Add` it reorders them correctly,

so is there a way to sort objects by their default insertion order ?

Comment: When you add a new item with an identity field, the id is 0 until it is saved.  So if you add 100 items, they all have an ID of 0.  So there is no way to order them this way.  If you want to ensure they get identities in sequential order based on how they were added, then you will have to save changes after every add.

Comment: but I can't save because the user have to validate the purchases first

Comment: why is this order relevant? Wouldn't it be simpler to add another property for order?

Comment: if you add order field you have to manage it manually on (addition, edition & deletion) that's why I've chosen the identity solution

Comment: Then use an explicit Transaction, and if the user doesn't validate the purchases, you rollback.  This will require escalation to a DTC, however if it's across multiple requests.

Comment: Another option is to add records that have a "Pending" flag, and when the user validates, you set all the pendings to false, and if they cancel, you delete all the records.  Then, periodically delete all pending requests that might have been orphaned by a worker process recycle or crash.

Comment: A Third option is to keep all the records in an ordered list, then when the user validates, write them all individually to the database.

Comment: I think am going with the third solution