# What logic determines the insert order of Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

So, I have a DBContext, and I am doing the following operations:

```
dbContext.SomeTables1.Add(object1)
dbContext.SomeTables2.AddRange(objectArray2)
dbContext.SomeTables3.AddRange(objectArray3)
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The EF doesn't insert the db records in this order, it inserts them in a random order. To insert them in the same order, I have to do a `dbContext.SaveChanges()` after each addition. This is not an efficient solution and in my case, it is taking 10 seconds to do all my inserts, while the random order with one save takes around 3 seconds.

N.B. I need the right order to solve a deadlock issue.

My questions are:

> - Is this issue resolved in EF7?
> - I can profile EF and determine the random order, however, is there a guarantee that it will be consistently with the same random order or
>     does it change between requests? (I can adopt my other code if the
>     answer to this question is positive).
> - Is there a better way of maintaining the order than `dbContext.SaveChanges()` on every addition?

Comment: It will not *really* help you, but it's interesting read though... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11521882/265165

Comment: What's EF 7? Are you referring to EF Core?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- There is no way you can specify a save order in EF6 or EF Core
- The issue is not resolved in EF Core since this is not an issue.
- The order will be the same if the predecessor is the same (which will likely rarely happen)

When you call SaveChanges, all entities are ordered from an internal order in the method “ProduceDynamicCommands” then sorted again by the method “TryTopologicalSort” which loops to add command with no predecessor left (if you add A and B and A depend on B, then B will be inserted before A)

You are left to insert by batch addition.

Since it takes you 3 seconds to perform your insert, I will assume you have thousands of entities and performing bulk insert may improve your performance to reduce the 10 seconds to less, and then maybe the initial 3 seconds!

To improve your performance, you can use http://entityframework-extensions.net/ (**PAID** but support all cases)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the Entity Framework Extensions project.

Comment: What's EF 7? Are you referring to EF Core?

Comment: Yes @Sнаđошƒаӽ, EF Core was initially named EF7.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to do it. It just thought I'd let you know:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   dbContext.SomeTables1.Add(object1);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();

   dbContext.SomeTables1.Add(object2);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();

   dbContextTransaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the contribution.  Transactions aren't required in a case like this, as the DBContext provides a database transaction, the dbContext.SaveChanges(), will do the actual insertion - hence the correct order.  Are you coming across a similar problem? If so, and it is an insertion order problem, I'd ask - why is the insertion order important? As in most cases, it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm working with a legacy database where there is an auto-incremental sequence_id and an insert_tmst for each new record. When I insert more than one record (in the same table), entities doesn't insert them in the order they are created, hence the insert_tmst and sequence_id aren't ordered properly. When using a transaction and saveChange after every new records it preserves the logic between insert_tmst and sequence_id and still allows be to rollback in case of error.
**I agree it's a bad database design, but I can't change it, it's a legacy application.

Comment: Ah ok. Does the database do the creation piece of the the sequence_id and the insert_tmst, and then something else that queries that - rely on the order?

Comment: The database manages the sequence_id, but not the insert_tmst. I know it's some sort of hack to bent the system so it does precisely what we want it to do, but I think it's still pretty clean, because we use the available object functionality to our advantage.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly set the values of the Primary Keys (and hence the order of the Clustered Index) in an Identity column in EF and EF Core, you need to manually turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` before calling `_context.SaveChanges()` after which you need to turn off `IDENTITY_INSERT` like so:
*This example assumes EF Core*

```
// Add your items with Identity Primary Key field manually set
_context.SomeTables1.AddRange(yourItems);
_context.Database.OpenConnection();
try {
      _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTables1 ON");
      _context.SaveChanges();
      _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTables1 OFF");
} finally {
      _context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: While this will work DBA are usually against using this and will probably not want to give you this kind of permission

Answer (score -1):

I've found a very simple solution.

Just set the property for the ID (primary key) of the entity to a value that matches your desired order.
SaveChanges() first sorts by this ID, then by other properties.
The assigned ID may already exist in the database. A unique ID is assigned when writing to the database.

```
for(int i = 0; i < objectArray2.Count(); i++)
{
   objectArray2[i].Id = i;
}

dbContext.SomeTables2.AddRange(objectArray2)
```

Comment: Are you quite sure about this? I get 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

If we set identity insert to ON, it will force us to manually assign the ID, which is dangerous. Or perhaps you're using a different setting?