# I need to do Multiple Breeze SaveChanges in one transaction

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, transactions, breeze, savechanges

I have a webpage that accepts a fee payment and it has to INSERT 6 rows, spread across 4 tables. I have had to break the INSERTS into two separate SaveChanges but I need them to both be within the same database transaction so that all INSERTS and UPDATES will rollback in case of a problem.

I'm using Breeze 1.6 on top of Entity Framework 6.2, on top of Oracle Mgd Data Access 12.2 in a SPA template.

The 4 tables are A, B, C, and D.  Tables B, C, and D are children of A, each carrying A's PK as a foreign key. I originally coded INSERTS in this sequence as required by my app A1, B1, C1, C2, C3, D1 and followed that by a single Breeze SaveChanges.  C3 has Oracle triggers that update a few columns in A1 and B1 at the time C3 is INSERTED. My problem is that Entity Framework was not INSERTING in the sequence I coded (and I understand I have no control over the sequence).  I was actually getting this sequence: A1, C1, C2, C3, B1, D1 and since C3 has a trigger that updates A and B, it ran into a problem because B wasn't INSERTED yet.

So I found this question: [What logic determines the insert order of Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795577/what-logic-determines-the-insert-order-of-entity-framework-6/) and it suggests using multiple SaveChanges to gain some control.  Got that working as follows:

- A1, B1 SaveChanges
- C1, C2, C3, D1 SaveChanges
  All triggers including the C3 update of A and B are working great now.

BUT Breeze/Entity Framework treats each SaveChanges as a transaction so now I can't rollback both parts in case of errors in the 2nd SaveChanges.  Am I going to have to code the Part 1 rollback myself in case of a Part 2 failure?  Or is there a secret I don't know?

I am familiar with BeginTransaction, Commit, and Rollback but not sure how/where to fit it in with Breeze and Entity Framework in the mix.  Breeze grabs each SaveChanges and wraps it in a transaction automatically.

I need to have multiple SaveChanges grouped into one Transaction.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: UPDATE: This is Visual Studio 2017, .Net FW 4.6.2, and for database I'm using Breeze 1.6 on top of Entity Framework 6.2, on top of Oracle Mgd Data Access 19.3 in a SPA template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do in this case is to let the Breeze *client* treat it as a single save, while the *server* breaks apart the save bundle to save it in the right order.

Let the Breeze `ContextProvider` deserialize the save bundle, then use the [BeforeSaveEntities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/contextprovider.html#beforesaveentities) hook to manually make the changes.  Finally,  mark the entities as `Unchanged` so that the ContextProvider won't try to save them again.

Here's an example implementation.

#### Server

On the server, in your Breeze Controller, create a new save method that adds a [BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate](http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/contextprovider.html#savechanges) that is
only used for this special save:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveFeePayment(JObject saveBundle) {
{
    contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate += BeforeSaveFeePayment;
    return contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}

private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveFeePayment(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> entities)
{
    var context = contextProvider.Context;

    // Get the list of EntityInfo for each type.  Throws exception if not found.
    // A fee payment save bundle must have A, B, C, and D or it is invalid.
    var ainfos = entities[typeof(A)];
    var binfos = entities[typeof(B)];
    var cinfos = entities[typeof(C)];
    var dinfos = entities[typeof(D)];

    using (var tx = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    {               
        // Save A and B
        Attach(context, ainfos);
        Attach(context, binfos);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // Save C and D
        Attach(context, cinfos);
        Attach(context, dinfos);
        context.SaveChanges();

        tx.Commit();
    }

    // Set all states to Unchanged, so Breeze won't try to save them again
    ainfos.ForEach(info => info.EntityState = Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged);
    binfos.ForEach(info => info.EntityState = Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged);
    cinfos.ForEach(info => info.EntityState = Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged);
    dinfos.ForEach(info => info.EntityState = Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged);

    // Return the entities, so Breeze will return them back to the client
    return entities;
}

// Map Breeze EntityState to EF EntityState
private static Dictionary<Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState, System.Data.Entity.EntityState> entityStateMap =
    new Dictionary<Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState, System.Data.Entity.EntityState> {
      { Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Added, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added },
      { Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Deleted, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted },
      { Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Detached, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached },
      { Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Modified, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified },
      { Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged }
    };

// Attach entities to the DbContext in the correct entity state 
private static void Attach(DbContext context, List<EntityInfo> infos)
{
    foreach(var info in infos)
    {
        var efState = entityStateMap[info.EntityState];
        context.Entry(info.Entity).State = efState;
    }
}
```

#### Client

On the client, you will need to call the `SaveFeePayment` endpoint using a [named save](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/saving-changes.html#NamedSave).  You'll do this *only when saving a fee payment*.  Continue use the normal `SaveChanges` endpoint for other saves.

Call the special endpoint by specifying the `resourceName`:

```
var saveOptions = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: "SaveFeePayment" });
return myEntityManager.saveChanges(null, saveOptions);
```

#### Transactions?

I haven't tested this example to be 100% about the transaction behavior.  I am not sure whether we should be using the existing `contextProvider.Context` or creating a new DbContext at the start of the method.  The difference is in how the database connections are handled.  See [Microsoft's guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions), and hope that it works the same with Oracle.

Hopefully your previous transaction management solution can be applied to the `BeforeSaveFeePayment` method above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks, Steve.  I just saw this.  Funny but I was just talking with our developer architect who said I need to deserialize the save bundle on the server, and put it in collections of the various types.  Then build multiple SaveChanges wrapped in a transaction.   Isn't that what you're doing?  (This will take a while for me to study and understand all you have here)  Thanks taking the time to help me.

Comment: Where does the BeginTransaction and the Commit/Rollback fit into this?

Comment: Yes, we are letting Breeze put the save bundle into collections of various types, then doing multiple SaveChanges.  

I've added a transaction block to the example, BUT I haven't tested it, and I am not sure whether we should be using the existing `contextProvider.Context` or creating a new DbContext at the start of the method.

Comment: Great job, Steve.  It all worked as you have written it.  One transaction containing 2 saveChanges, and both rollback everything in case of a failure.  I've learned a lot.  Love the Breeze NAMED SAVES.  And it was very helpful to understand how to address the pieces of the saveBundle.   Good stuff.  Thanks much.

Comment: Hi Steve, I just used this same scenario for doing deletes to the same 4 A,B,C,D tables because a C trigger was checking to make sure there were no more D's and the D hadn't been deleted, even though that was the first one I turned on the Deleted status for.  So I needed to delete D, then all the A-B-C's in 2 save changes.

Comment: However, something happened this time that wasn't a problem on the inserts.  The saveBundle didn't clear out after the commit, and it left some of the rows in there marked as Deleted.  So the next time I tried to add or delete a fee, they were still hanging around in the saveBundle and it tried to delete those rows again that had already been deleted, and of course they weren't there.  So I got a concurrency error - I guess because it assumed somebody else beat me to the delete.

Comment: Is there a way to detach those entities from the context or reinitialize the context?  Any other delete of a single table clears the context and the deleted row doesn't get held over.  It's just something with this process causing problems. Funny thing is that the D is gone but the A-B-C's are still hanging around with Status of Deleted.  The rows are gone from the database as desired, though, and triggers are happy. By the way, the "return entities" were all marked as Unchanged, as desired, at the time of the return.

Comment: Right, you need to return the deleted status back to the client.  I think it should be 

`deletedInfos.ForEach(info => info.EntityState = Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Detached);`

but maybe it should be `EntityState.Deleted`.  Please try both.

Comment: Thanks.  The Detached has just about solved the problem!! I came across that value last night and tried it.  Most of my deletes are working now too.

Comment: Have one interesting problem where I do an insert followed by a delete of the same set of rows.  For some reason, the D table row (which is deleted by itself first) ends up being in the saveBundle twice, but only if it was just added. It's there once with Deleted status and secondary column key being 1 which is correct, but also once with Modified status and the secondary identity key being -1.  I'm going to have to try to figure out what's going on there.  May try Attach D and A and Save Changes.  Then B and C and save changes to see if I get 2 A's too.  Just too weird.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: All is working, for both 2 SaveChanges (INSERTS and DELETES).  I had an extra row that wasn't getting deleted and it caused concurrency problems the next time around.  My bad.  But setting all statuses to DETACHED after the delete was needed, rather than setting to UNCHANGED in the end.

Comment: Great, glad you solved the problem.  And glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Breeze on .NET core 3.1, I had to set `IsTemporary=true`, as seen in the following code sample:

```cs
private static void Attach(BreezeContext context, List<EntityInfo> infos)
{
  foreach (var info in infos)
  {
    var efState = entityStateMap[info.EntityState];

    context.Entry(info.Entity).Property("Id").IsTemporary = true; //Explicitly set to true
    context.Entry(info.Entity).State = efState;
  }
}
```

By default, this is set to `false` and, hence, `SaveChanges()` was throwing the following error:

> "cannot insert explicit value for identity column"

This may be due to a bug in Breeze. In the meanwhile, setting `IsTemporary` to `true` at least works around the problem.