# Dictionary to List Insertion order

Tags: c#, dictionary

When a Dictionary is converted to a List, does the order of the List correlate to the insertion order of items into the Dictionary. In this example insertion order is preserved, but is this always the case? Or is it how the Dictionary decides to store its items.

```
     Dictionary<string, int> test = new Dictionary<string, int>
     { 
         {"A",0},
         {"Z",1},
         {"F",2},
         {"J",3}
     };

     List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> testlist = 
         new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>(test);
```

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387874/is-there-a-an-easier-way-to-initialize-a-listkeyvaluepairt-u-like-a-dictio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know this for sure is to look at the code, so let's do that...

The implementation of the constructor you are calling of `List<T>`, when decompiled, looks like

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  if (collection == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
  ICollection<T> collection1 = collection as ICollection<T>;
  if (collection1 != null)
  {
    int count = collection1.Count;
    if (count == 0)
    {
      this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
    }
    else
    {
      this._items = new T[count];
      collection1.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
      this._size = count;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    this._size = 0;
    this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
    foreach (T obj in collection)
      this.Add(obj);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the dictionary is cast to `ICollection<T>` and then `CopyTo` is called on it which leads us to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

```
private void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
{
  if (array == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.array);
  if (index < 0 || index > array.Length)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum);
  if (array.Length - index < this.Count)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall);
  int num = this.count;
  Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Entry[] entryArray = this.entries;
  for (int index1 = 0; index1 < num; ++index1)
  {
    if (entryArray[index1].hashCode >= 0)
      array[index++] = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(entryArray[index1].key, entryArray[index1].value);
  }
}
```

From looking at the code, the internal items of the dictionary are *indexed* into.

Based on these findings, if what you are asking is *"will the order of my dictionary be retained when it's converted to a generic list?"* - then yes it will be (as per .NET 4.0 which is the version I am looking at). However, the problem is you can't actually guarantee the order of your items being added to the *dictionary* to start with. So my advice would be switch to using something like `OrderedDictionary<T>` or apply an `OrderBy` clause before you convert it e.g.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<K, V>>(test.OrderBy(x => x.Value));
```

Comment: @MagnusHoff the way I picked the question up was "*when I create a new list based off a dictionary, will my items be in the same order*" so my answer was based on that. I will update for clarification. AZ. yeah fair enough, I will add a disclaimer for that.

Answer (score 5):

NO. It does not preserve the order. If it does it's just by accident and an internal implementation detail. There is no guarantee that the enumeration order of elements should be the same as the insertion order.
Documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2#remarks):

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: why so many downvotes for a correct answer? Or are you guys trying to imply that relating on not documented, prone to change and accidental implementation details is something to be encouraged?

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary does not guarantee order of items.

You need [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) if you want to maintain order items where added to it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does *usually* preserve insertion order, but this may not be guaranteed and you should not rely on it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."

Comment: I think if it does preserve order it's generally just coincidental, looking at the [implementation](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary@cs/1305376/Dictionary@cs) of `Insert` it uses the HashCode of the key to work out it's order.

Comment: It often does, but one should not rely on it regardless.