# How to Remove and add a key which should be added in last location?

Tags: c#, .net

When I remove Dictionary key add then add new key to dictionary new value is not added to last location. Instead of its adding in the key where it is removed.

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 dic.Add(1, "a");
 dic.Add(2, "b");
 dic.Add(3, "c");

 dic.Remove(2);

 dic.Add(4, "d");
```

I want output as

```
1 "a"
3 "c"
4 "d"
```

Not as

```
1 "a"
4 "d"
3 "c"
```

Comment: If you care about ordering, you're using the wrong type, a Dictionary is not the answer here.

Comment: not ordering. it should be in any order but i want to add it in last not in the key removed location.

Comment: If you are concerned with _location_ you are concerned with _ordering_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic Key/Value pair collection in that preserves insertion order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396718/generic-key-value-pair-collection-in-that-preserves-insertion-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage the sorting by yourself, you can use a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`. In a list you use the `Insert`-method to insert the item at the position you want. The order in the list remains.

Answer (score 4):

`Dictionary`s are not guaranteed to be in the order of insertion. `SortedDictionary`s are:

```
SortedDictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dic.Add(1, "a");
dic.Add(2, "b");
dic.Add(3, "c");

dic.Remove(2);

dic.Add(4, "d");
```

Produces:

```
1 "a"
3 "c"
4 "d"
```

Comment: SortedDictionary is in .NET 2.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: if key is not in sorted order then?

Comment: If the key is not in a sorted order, then what you are trying to do is a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. This is the only way to directly preserve order of insertion and not sort by anything else, unless you want to create a custom type.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries do not necessarily preserve ordering. Your either looking for the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class, or should just sort the key value pairs when printing your results.

Comment: dic.Add(1, "a");
            dic.Add(2, "b");
            dic.Add(3, "c");


            dic.Remove(2);

            dic.Add(0, "d");

Comment: if it is not in sorted order then?

Comment: see my answer, the enumeration order is undefined as per the msdn documentation

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

As stated by others, you need a data structure that preserves order such as a `SortedDictionary` (preserves order by value) or a `SortedList` (preserves insertion order). (see 4.0 versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) and 2.0 versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` is unsorted. (Random access map)

You can use **[SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)** to keep it sorted by key.

Or if you want to sort by value (not key) check this out:

[How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value)