# How to get the key of the first max value in a C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, max

I want to get the keys of the highest values in a `dictionary` `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 2}`. In this case I want it to return `'b'` but use of

```
weight.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key;
```

returns the last largest value i.e. `'c'`.

1. Is there a way to return the key of the first largest value in my dictionary? =>`'b'`
2. Also, is it possible to return an array of keys of the max tied values? => `new char[]{'b', 'c'}`
3. Which Key-Value data structure should I use instead?

**EDIT:** Since it has caused quite a stir in the comments, I mean the first largest value in terms of insertion order.

Comment: `Dictionary<K, V>` are not stable.

Comment: Dictionarys do not have a concept of "first". A software update, and suddenly it might start returning `c` instead, or alternating between options every time you run it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn there is an OrderedDictionary for that, never really used it.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues are you talking about Python or C#?

Comment: @user14773854 C#, python dictionaries have been ordered for a while. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0

Comment: Dictionary<char,int> dict = new Dictionary<char,int>{{'a', 1}, {'b',2}, {'c', 2}};

            var results = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).GroupBy(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1396718/2501279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722767/2501279) can point into right direction.

Comment: @GuruStron Unfortuately `MaxBy` is not supported on my compiler...

Comment: @user14773854 your `Aggregate` in question is effectively `MaxBy` so it is not hard to implement/adapt that to the grouped values. Though it will not fix the issue that C# dictionary does not guarantee to preserve insertion order.

Comment: Will you modify the dictionary after creation(add/delete)? If so, it might be that you first get 'b' and later you will get a different char from the highest-value-group. You want the first in insertion order or the first alphabetically? Also, do you need the fast lookup capability of a dictionary at all? Otherwise you are free to build a simple `List<YourClass>` which makes it simple and reliable.

Comment: If you want MaxBy and dont want to write it yourself you can install MoreLinq or use .NET 6

Comment: So.. I'm curious *why* you're using a Dictionary? Do you really need key lookup? Or is it just being used as list of KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For the sake of suggesting something)

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580202/how-do-i-override-listts-add-method-in-c#answer-580213), I am going to suggest an approach where you create your own type that inherits from `List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>` (thereby preserving insertion order), and hides the `base.Add()` method using a method that ensures that only entries with unique `key`s are added to your list.

This works nicely for your specific use case if you can add your items one by one, and if *adding* items to your list is the only way you intend to change your list content. If there is a chance you may need to e.g. remove items from your list, the implementation needs to be extended to cover that.

Also worth mentioning: This implementation lets an incident of trying to add an entry with a non-unique key to the list pass silently. There's no screaming; the entry is simply not added.

Implementation:

```
public class UniqueKeyKvpList : List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>
{
    private readonly HashSet<char> _keys = new HashSet<char>();

    // Hiding base method List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>.Add()
    public new void Add(KeyValuePair<char, int> kvp) => Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    
    // Simpler .Add() method; imitates Dictionary.Add() in usage
    public void Add(char key, int value) => AddIfUniqueKey(key, value);

    private void AddIfUniqueKey(char key, int value)
    {
        if (!_keys.Contains(key))
        {
            _keys.Add(key);
            base.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(key, value));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myKvpList = new UniqueKeyKvpList();

myKvpList.Add('a', 1);
myKvpList.Add('a', 2); // will not be added (duplicate key)
myKvpList.Add('b', 3);
```

---

After populating the list, you can get *all chars with the max value* as follows:

**.Net 6** (due to use of [`.MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0))

```
char[] charsWithMaxValue = myKvpList
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .MaxBy(gr => gr.Key) // Group key is the kvp value
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

**< .Net 6**

```
char[] charsWithMaxValue = myKvpList
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Key) // Group key is the kvp value
    .First()
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

The *first char with the max value* will then be

```
char firstCharWithMaxValue = charsWithMaxValue.First();
```

Alternatively, if computing `charsWithMaxValue` is not needed for anything, `firstCharWithMaxValue` can be calculated directly as follows:

**.Net 6**

```
char firstCharWithMaxValue = myKvpList
    .MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .Key;
```

**< .Net 6**

```
char firstCharWithMaxValue = myKvpList
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .First()
    .Key;
```

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0t2STu).