# Unique set of strings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, unique

I have a list of strings, I need to be able to simply probe if a new string is in the table or not. When the list is large, testing a simple list directly is pretty inefficient... so typically I use a Dictionary to get constant lookup speeds, although I don't actually care about the value. This seems like a misuse of a dictionary, so I'm wondering what other approaches I could take.

Is there a better way to do hit testing that I am unaware of?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860306/net-how-to-efficiently-check-for-uniqueness-in-a-liststring-of-50-000-items/1860311#1860311

Comment: Hit-testing means checking whether a point is inside of something.  (eg, a circle or a control).

Comment: I suppose I was thinking of something similar to a "cache hit" when I said hit-test

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), which is specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A HashSet is better suited than a Dictionary, for this purpose.