# Is there a collection in .NET that works as a dictionary and list at the same time?

Tags: .net, list, collections, dictionary, generic-collections

What I want is basically a collection that's a hybrid of a dictionary and a list. I want a collection that I can add key/value pairs to (like a Dictionary), but at the same be able to retrieve the values (without the keys) in the same order I added them (like a List)? Does such a collection exists in .NET?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of ["LinkedHashMap" in C# 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/linkedhashmap-in-c-sharp-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing in the framework which implements this functionality at the moment (but see edit below).

Basically you would want to compose a `List<T>` and a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in your own class.

EDIT: I had genuinely forgotten about `OrderedDictionary` as pointed out by wesleyhill - but I don't believe there's a *generic* collection in the framework like this. I assume you'd actually want a generic collection? You could write a wrapper around `OrderedDictionary` of course...

EDIT: Quick note: while wrapping the collection shouldn't be hard at all, you'll lose one benefit of generic collections: avoiding boxing. Not an issue if your keys and values are reference types, of course.

Comment: I beg to differ; please see my answer to this question.

Comment: Jon, you can do better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/linkedhashmap-in-c-3-0 (have a look at your answer)

Comment: @wesleyhill: I'd forgotten about that, but I assume the OP wants a generic collection anyway, in which case they'd at least need to wrap this. @fielding: Yeah, I don't really have time for that at the moment :)

Answer (score 13):

There is a non-generic data-structure called [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) which does what you want. It has two indexers, one which takes an `Object` and does the key/value lookup, and one which takes an `int` and does an index lookup. You can also enumerate the contents in the order in which you added them.

I don't see anything in the documentation though about whether the dictionary lookup achieves *O*(1) (i.e. fast) behaviour. Given that it implements `ISerializable` it's highly likely that it uses objects' hash codes, and hence has *O*(1) dictionary lookup.

You could also create your own generic type which encapsulates both a `List<T>` and a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: I definatly have an old implementation of this in VB.NET and may have a newer version in C# if you are interested? The TValue is stored in a `List<TValue>` while there is a dictionary used for key to index lookup `Dictionary<TKey, int>`.

Comment: This is actually what I need, except that I'm looking for a generic collection. But I might use that one after all. Thanks very much.

Comment: You just outscored Jon Skeet's answer. OMG

Answer (score 2):

[System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) is very close to what you're asking for, except the dictionary key must be derivable from the value.

Comment: +1 This should have been awarded the question. I have used `KeyedCollection<K,T>` plenty of times and it works great. Internally it does keep a `List<T>` and a `Dictionary<K,T>` synced.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new class which wraps dictionary
- when adding data, wrap the data in a little helper class which introduces an index
- when returning the values, order them according the index

wouldnt be a performance monster but should work fine. Otherwise you could implement your own [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as in Java.

By the way, have a look at this:
[LinkedHashMap in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/linkedhashmap-in-c-3-0)

edit:
I do like wesleyhills idea even more: encapsulate List and Dictionary in one class. Add always to both and return the List instead of Dictionary.Values.