# List of KeyValuePair

Tags: .net

Why does .NET not provide a class for a `List<KeyValuePair<T, U>>`?

I think there are a lot of situations when you need to keep an array of pairs. For example,

```
1; 2      "a"; "array"
5; 8      "b"; "browser"
1; 9      "f"; "Firefox"
8; 10     "f"; "frequency"
```

À la:

```
Pairs<int, int> myPairs;

myPairs.Add(10, 8);
myPairs.Add(5, 8);
myPairs.Add(10, 5);
myPairs.Add(1, 4);

myPairs[0].Value1 = 5;
myPairs[5].Value2 = 8;
```

Comment: ... why not just use `List<KeyValuePair<T, U>>`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: is a little "difficult" to build it. -  I mean you should code a little building keyValuePairs, then aggregate them into a list. Finally why a List<U> was built? You could use Arrays! :)

Comment: It's easier to use Tuple than KeyValuePair - and more appropriate too.

Comment: Could this be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/linkedhashmap-in-net? It seems that that's what he needs, right?
@Jon: Ever got round to a quick implementation?

Comment: @wensveen: I don't see any indication that that's needed here - the OP didn't indicate that they need to look up by key.

Comment: @Jon: No, you're right. I think I was reading too much into the use of KeyValuePair. List of Tuples is the most correct answer then (and should be marked as such). I get the idea that serhio wasn't really even asking a question, but just frustrated about something missing in his opinion.

Answer (score 9):

This seems completely unnecessary to me - and just because you have a pair of values doesn't mean it's necessarily a key/value relation either.

.NET 4 introduced the `Tuple` family of types... unless this really *was* a key/value pair, I'd use `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>` instead - and I see no reason for a single type to exist in order to encapsulate that construct.

EDIT: To put this into context, here's how "difficult" it is to use `Tuple` here, converting your sample code:

```
var myPairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
    Tuple.Create(10, 8),
    Tuple.Create(5, 8),
    Tuple.Create(10, 5),
    Tuple.Create(1, 4),
};
```

Now tuples are immutable, so you wouldn't be able to set the values directly as per the last part of your code... but the beauty of *composing* the two concepts of "list" and "pair of values" is that you could easily write your own `MutableTuple` type and use exactly the same code... whereas if you had one collection class which was hard-wired to `Tuple` or some other type, you wouldn't have that flexibility.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to have relation between values. See topic edit as example. You could also use `Pairs<int, MyBusonessObject>` or whatever you want.

Comment: @serhio: In that case you don't want KeyValuePair, but `List<Tuple<...>>` should be fine for you.

Comment: your example will be a little less "beautiful" when adding items in a foreach in such a structure, or modifying its values.

Comment: @serhio: You'd have to give a more concrete example, but I expect it would still be perfectly fine. You could still use `Tuple.Create` which is far from awful... or you could use LINQ to generate the sequence in a more declarative manner to start with.

Comment: practical example: I need a collection of points(x, y) to pass to a function, without addind the namespace System.Drawing I am forced to use 2 lists of integers, or a Tuple, or a list of KeyValuePair...

Comment: @serhio: Yes, that is a practical example. But everyone has perfectly practical needs which are not universal; that's what you write your own types for. No one's arguing that *you* shouldn't write a collection type to encapsulate a list of 2-value points which meets your needs; this question is about why such a type doesn't exist in the BCL. Fortunately, *if* you need such a thing, as I keep saying, it is very easy to do.

Comment: @serhio: Why would you not create your own Point type in that case? There you've got an obvious target for encapsulation: the two values are clearly related. Using Tuple or (worse) KeyValuePair would be wholly inappropriate IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Why stop there? Why not a list of triplets? Or quadruplets?

The fact is that this is **very** trivial to write yourself. Write a class that derives from `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, add an `Add` method that takes 2 parameters.

```
public class KeyValueList<TKey, TValue> : List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}
```

Boom, you're done.

---

**Further comments**: Note that `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is an immutable type (as is `Tuple<T1, T2>` in .NET 4.0); so if you'd want to be able to do something like this:

```
list[0].Value = 5;
```

...then you'd need a mutable type, something like:

```
public sealed class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 X { get; set; }
    public T2 Y { get; set; }
}

public class PairList<T1, T2> : List<Pair<T1, T2>>
{ /* ...same as KeyValueList<T1, T2>, basically... */ }
```

Also note that this would enable nice initialization syntax:

```
var list = new PairList<int, string>
{
    { 1, "dan" },
    { 2, "serhio" }
};
```

But *again*, the point here is that this is very easy and very trivial and thus not really deserving of its own type in the framework. Look at it this way: can you name any type in the BCL that is essentially just *another* type but with one single convenience method added?

---

**Closing comments**: You have posed these questions:

- Why introduce a `List<T>` type when you could just use a `T[]` array?
- Why introduce a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type when you could just use a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`?

These are bizarre questions, honestly. Why introduce OOP at all when you can just do everything with procedural code and global variables? Why introduce higher-level programming languages like C#, C++, or even C when you could just write everything in Assembly?

The `List<T>` class provides a **useful encapsulation** of all the functionality that goes into accessing elements in an array, maintaining the number of items, resizing the array as necessary, etc. There is a *big difference* between what you can do with a `List<T>` and what you can do with just a `T[]`.

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` also encapsulates the functionality of maintaining a collection of values associated with unique keys. It also provides killer O(1) lookup time on those keys. There is a *huge difference* between a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

The difference between a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and your proposed `KeyValueList<TKey, TValue>` (as I've called it above) is practically nil. Hardly anything new is encapsulated. It just *is* a `List<T>`. Honestly the benefit is, to me, hardly greater than adding an `Int32List` type that just wraps a `List<int>`.

There's just no reason to add such a type to the BCL.

Comment: is quite trivial to write a Dictionary yoursef too. However this class exists in .NET

Comment: @serhio: You think it's trivial to implement Dictionary properly and efficiently? I beg to differ.

Comment: and triplets are not so often used. The problem of multikeys dictionary is often asked, but only in .NET 3.5 the LookUp class appears.

Comment: @serhio: What?! It's trivial to write a hashtable yourself? I think that is a big stretch, compared to the code I just posted.

Comment: @serhio: My point in mentioning triplets was just that the argument for incorporating such a type into the BCL is dwarfed (in my opinion) by the triviality of implementing your own type that does what you want. People have been making strongly-typed collections for their custom types since before generics (since before .NET, actually). It seems to me you are essentially asking why there is not a collection type for your specific type. That type just happens to be a generic key-value pair.

Comment: so, OK, you've done a good implementation. So you think that is not so frequently used in order to include it in the Framework?

Comment: @serhio: no, it's not. What do you gain? A little bit of syntactic sugar. That's not enough of a plus to overcome the negatives of having a new class in the BCL that needs to be documented and tested.

Comment: If the purpose of the list is to hold pairs of values, a `List<MutableTupleClass<T1,T2>>` would not be a terribly good fit, since each slot of such a list would not hold a `(T1,T2)` pair, but rather identify an object which not only holds such a pair, but *may be referenced elsewhere*.  It would probably be better to use an array of a struct type, and manually handle the associated count and size issues, since e.g. given a `Point[] arr`, a statement like `arr[4].X += 5;` can be relied upon to safely update `arr[4].X` without affecting any other `Point` anywhere in the universe.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to define a class `MutableStructHolder<T> where T:struct` with an exposed `Value` field *(not property)*, and which supports implicit casts to and from `T`, along with a `StructList<T>` whose indexer accepts or returns a `MutableStructHolder<T>` (the setter should create a new `MutableStructHolder` with data copied from the passed-in one).  Given a `StructList<Point> list`, one could then say `list[4].Value.X += 5;` and know that it would only affect the one item's value.

Comment: Who you kidding? `C` IS assembly, for all intents and purposes (for the PDP-11) with some syntactic sugar thrown in for good measure.

Answer (score 3):

What's stopping you from using a `List<KeyValuePair<T, V>>` directly? And, if you know `T` and `V`, you can alias it at the top of your source file:

```
using KeyValueList = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<MyNS.MyKeyType, MyNS.MyValueType>>;

// in your code...
KeyValueList list = new KeyValueList();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<MyKeyType, MyValueType>(..., ...));
```

Comment: see the answer to the remark. Why a List<U> was built? You could use Arrays! :)

Comment: and, finally, the question is not that I can't use, but why is not present a more "commode" class.

Comment: `list.Add(new KeyValuePair<MyKeyType, MyValueType>(..., ...));` not so pretty. and in VB.NET worse that than.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What do you want to do with a `KeyValueList<T, U>` that you can't with a `List<KeyValuePair<T, U>>`?

Comment: @thecoop: My answer remains the same: Why you don't use an int[] but List<int> ? Why a Dictionary class was created, when you just could use List<KeyValuePairs>? etc.

Comment: because a dictionary has an O(1) lookup time, whereas to get at a particular item in a list requires you to scan the list

Comment: A List is a dynamic structure while an array in c# is a fixed length defined on creation. You can change the length by creating a new array and assigning it to the same variable but that requires copying of the whole array. Also, lists implement a number of methods not present in array.

Comment: @serhio: You realize a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is *not* just a wrapper for a list of key-value pairs, right?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is a specialized collection that is optimized for key/value pairs. While you are free to create a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, you are short-changing yourself as you will not have optimized access to your keys are values.

Comment: `Dictionary<k, v>` doesn't allow duplicate keys and might have an additional overhead if only sequential access is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, that's a KeyValue store ;)

It's pure `(string, string)` mapping, but then most key value situations would work with that.

Or make a subclass of `System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase` for a special solution for your object type.

Comment: NameValueCollection is not generic. Have no Add method.

Comment: No but then, as soon as you go with generics there is an infinite number of possibilities. I have so many different combinations of list in my code that a special for Key Value would actually just complicate things, better to have a given solution that works for all.

Comment: don't understand the point. The scope of generics is to reduce your "possibilities" in a one single class: `Pairs<T, U>` (see the example in my edit)

Comment: Then why complain that there is not a specialised class for this situation. Hashtable and Dictionary could handle most keyvalue situations and if you require something else you can design you own around existing solutions ;)