# C# 2 string arrays to List<string, string>

Tags: c#

Assuming the 2 string arrays are the same length and not empty how can I make a List of the contents?

I had a Dictionary working, but now I need to be able to use duplicate keys so I am resorting to a List.

```
string[] files = svd.file.Split(",".ToCharArray());
string[] references = svd.references.Split(",".ToCharArray());

Dictionary<string, string> frDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

frDictionary = files.Zip(rReferences, (s, i) => new { s, i })
.ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
```

I could do it like:

```
List<string, string> jcList = new List<string, string>();
```

and then just have a double loop into the two arrays but I know a faster way must exist.

Comment: `",".ToCharArray() == ','`

Comment: If you are starting to make up your own types (list doesnt have a string, string overload.)  You might as well just make your own class with properties to hold the data.

Comment: You can't have `List<string, string>`.

Comment: Maybe List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>? Don't think there is a restriction on unique key, but could be wrong.

Comment: `Pete` if you want to use something that would be equivalent to `List<string, string>` then you can use an `Immutable Struct`
[C# SO Immutable Struct List<string,string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231460/define-a-list-like-listint-string)

Comment: I think this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4806256/417579

Comment: @spender Technically, `",".ToCharArray != ','`, but `",".ToCharArray().SequenceEqual(new[] { ',' })` ... but I get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List containing elements with two strings each is simplest implemented with a

```
List<T>
```

and

```
T == Tuple<string,string>
```

Then use a loop to build your list from the two arrays:

```
string[] s1 =
{
    "1", "2"
};
string[] s2 =
{
    "a", "b"
};

var jcList = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
{
    jcList.Add(Tuple.Create(s1[i], s2[i]));
}
```

or using LINQ:

```
var jcList = s1.Select((t, i) => Tuple.Create(t, s2[i])).ToList();
```

Comment: with just code the OP can't understand what you are doing. Add some documentation to it

Comment: `-1` LOL I totally agree `VDesign` wow talk about over thinking in my opinion I would not skin my cat this way.. sorry

Comment: FYI instad of `new Tuple<string, string>(s1[i], s2[i])` you can use `Tuple.Create(s1[i], s2[i])`.

Comment: please note: with spender's Lookup any search will be (much) faster than with this simple flat List

Answer (score 12):

```
ILookup<string,string> myLookup = 
    files.Zip(rReferences, (s, i) => new { s, i })
         .ToLookup(item => item.s, item => item.i);
```

will create a `Dictionary`-like structure that allows multiple values per key.

So

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = myLookup["somestring"];
```