# How to use Java Linked Hash MAP and Tree Map in c#

Tags: c#, data-structures

How can use LinkedHashMap feature in C#...

I use LinkedHashMap in JAVA.. like

```
private Map<ShapeId, List<Shape>> children = new LinkedHashMap();
```

But in c# i cannot use LinkedHashMap()..

How use LinkedHashMap() in C#

Comment: This question is not **about** Java, so it shouldn't be tagged "java".

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinkedHashMap in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/linkedhashmap-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

The closest is `Dictionary<ShapeId, List<shape>>`.  See the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.